# How to apply shadow to interior views in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have added a shadow around the `VStack` that holds my two text fields and a submit button. However, the shadow is also being applied to the two text fields inside the `VStack`.

Is there something I am missing here that is causing this to happen? I tried adding `shadow(radius: 0)` on the text fields, but it doesn't change anything. If I remove the padding and background from the text fields, then the shadow goes away.

```swift
var body: some View {
    VStack() {
        Spacer()

        VStack() {
            TextField($email, placeholder: Text("email"))
                .padding()
                .background(Color(red: 242 / 255, green: 242 / 255, blue: 242 / 255))

            SecureField($password, placeholder: Text("password"))
                .padding()
                .background(Color(red: 242 / 255, green: 242 / 255, blue: 242 / 255))

            Button(action: { self.login() }, label: { Text("Login").foregroundColor(Color.white) })
                .padding()
                .background(Color(red: 0, green: 116 / 255, blue: 217 / 255))
        }
        .padding()
        .background(Color.white)
        .shadow(radius: 10)

        Spacer()
    }
    .padding()
    .background(Color(red: 0, green: 116 / 255, blue: 217 / 255))
    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
}
```

Comment: A view's children inheriting the shadow of the parent view seems like a bug to me

Comment: @ielyamani No this is not a bug there is a solution

Answer (score 75, accepted):

You can use `clipped()` here to fix this

```swift
VStack() {
    Text("Text")
        .background(Color.red)
        .padding()
        .padding()

    Text("Text")
        .background(Color.purple)
        .padding()
}
.padding()
.background(Color.white)

.clipped()
.shadow(color: Color.red, radius: 10, x: 0, y: 0)
```

Output:

[image]

Hope it is helpful :)

Comment: This hack works evengthough you haven’t explained it does. Yet, this is not the definition given by Apple to `clipped()`. The inheritance of the shadow modifier still seems like a bug to me.

Comment: @ielyamani This is how VStack and HStack works. If you provide any  modifier to  VStack it will automatically applied to it's child items. like `foregroundColor(Color.red)`  will make all the `Text` inside VStack to be red if **Text has not it's own foregroundColor()**

Comment: Still doesn’t explain why is the VStack has shadow and its children don’t

Comment: @ielyamani if you remove `.clipped()` then all the child has shadow

Comment: It doesn't work for me. I still get the shadow around the children.

Comment: `.clipped()` doesn't help me as well, it still applies `.shadow` to each nested view.

Comment: Your'e better off just doing `.background(Color.white.shadow(color: Color.red, radius: 10, x: 0, y: 0)`

Comment: @user1366265 and zh - You can use `compositingGroup` as proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64795809/8697793)

Comment: `clipped` is clipping the view after all. A better alternative is to create background and apply shadow on the background. See this simple other answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59431517/4659467

Answer (score 40):

For me it also worked to apply the shadow to the background instead of the Stack, e.g:

```swift
VStack {
  // ...
}.background(Rectangle().fill(Color.white).shadow(radius: 8))
```

Comment: You can just use simple `Color.white` instead of `Rectangle().fill(Color.white)` to create a colored rectangle 

Comment: This is the correct answer. Using `clipped()` has caused weird effects on children views with corner radius

Comment: Using `clipped()` also caused problems for me when using offsets

Answer (score 35):

There is a **dedicated modifier** for this - `compositingGroup`.

From [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/capsule/compositinggroup()/):

```
/// Wraps this view in a compositing group.
///
/// A compositing group makes compositing effects in this view's ancestor
/// views, such as opacity and the blend mode, take effect before this view
/// is rendered.
/// [...] 
/// This limits the scope of [...] change to the outermost view.
```

```
VStack {
    Text("Text")
        .background(Color.red)
        .padding()
        .padding()
    Text("Text")
        .background(Color.purple)
        .padding()
}
.padding()
.background(Color.white)
.compositingGroup()
.shadow(color: Color.red, radius: 10, x: 0, y: 0)
```

Comment: The best answer as `compositingGroup` works as expected. Though `clipped()` worked for me, it seems more of a side effect.

Comment: This is true answer, however, seem not working all the time, sometimes, one need to apply this where the Custom View is used.

Answer (score 11):

For the user's who are struggling to have this work for `RoundedRectangle`, use:

```
HStack {
 // Your nested views
}
.overlay(
  RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
   .stroke(Color.black.opacity(0.2), lineWidth: 1)
)
.background(
   RoundedRectangle(
     cornerRadius: 10
   )
   .foregroundColor(Color.white)
   .shadow(
     color: Color.black,
     radius: 5,
     x: 0,
     y: 0
   )
)
```

The shadow is applied in the `.background`, `RoundedRectagle` element `shadow`.

While quite verbose, it's easy to read and the same principle can be applied to and from any other shape.

Answer (score 1):

You can work around the issue by using a `ZStack` to put a `Rectangle`,`Capsule`,`Circle` or other shape behind the `VStack`. Then apply modifiers to the shape instead of the VStack itself.

```
ZStack() {
    Capsule()
        .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
        .background(Color.white)
        .shadow(radius: 10)

    VStack() {
        //...
    }
}
```

Seems like a pretty annoying feature to me, there are many times when you would want a shadow on a container without it being applied to all its elements.

If anyone knows a better way please share, thanks!

Comment: I've never seen a use case for applying a shadow to all the children so you have shadows on shadows. But maybe there is.

Answer (score 1):

Hello i'm using only this at the moment but it serves it's purpose - allows me to have inner shadow.

With some modification you can have what you want.

```
private struct InnerShadow: ViewModifier {

    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        HStack(spacing: .zero) {
            verticalLine().offset(x: -1)
            VStack(spacing: .zero) {
                horizontalLine().offset(y: -1)
                content
                horizontalLine().offset(y: 1)
            }
            verticalLine().offset(x: 1)
        }

    }

    private func verticalLine() -> some View {
        Rectangle()
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .frame(maxWidth: 1, maxHeight: .infinity)
            .shadow(radius: 4)

    }

    private func horizontalLine() -> some View {
        Rectangle()
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: 1)
            .shadow(radius: 4)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `.clipped()` (as some other answers suggest) can lead to some undesirable side-effects in some situations. Drawing an extra view using `.background()` and giving that a shadow is inefficient (in terms of compute) and tedious.

The best way to do this is to call `.compositingGroup()` on your VStack. That will look like this:

```
VStack {
    // Some inner views
}
.compositingGroup()
```

Per [this page](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/compositinggroup()) from the Apple Developer Documentation:

> A compositing group makes compositing effects in this view’s ancestor views, such as opacity and the blend mode, take effect before this view is rendered.

Because the view and its children get composited as a single `View`, any shadows applied to it don't get propagated to the children.