# SwiftUI: How to apply modifiers only to specific elements?

Tags: ios, swiftui

So i have this very simplified code, where I basically have an HStack with a custom modifier.

My question is, how can i keep the modifier on the HStack, but dont let the modifier apply to the button inside the HStack?

In this case i could just apply the modifier directly to the textfield, but as i mentioned, this is a very simplified version of my code, so let’s just assume the modifier has to be on the HStack

This is the code

```
HStack{
    TextField("Enter a Froot", text: self.$searchTxt)
     
    Button(action: {print("Is cancelled")}){
        Text("Cancel")
    }                
}.modifier(TFModifier())
```

This is the modifier

```
struct TFModifier : ViewModifier {
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content.padding()
            .background(Color("TesterColor"))
            .overlay(
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
                    .stroke(Color.black.opacity(0.01), lineWidth: 4)
                    .shadow(color:  Color("TesterColor3"), radius: 6, x: 5, y: 5)
                    .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20))
            )
    }
}
```

Comment: I added your code to a project and it seems to be working as expected. The TFModifier is on the HStack only. What's the issue here?

Comment: I dont want the modifier to apply to the button @nicksarno

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to apply shadow to interior views in SwiftUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56518868/how-to-apply-shadow-to-interior-views-in-swiftui)

Answer (score 0):

In your case ViewModifier, thinks the content is entire HStack which is actually you are latterly telling to SwiftUI take my HStack as Content and as content modify it with TFModifier! in this case there is no way to tell SwiftUI put Button out of calculation! It is 100% impossible! SwiftUI does not care about your naming like **TFModifier**, it just care about incoming content! and like I said you are feeding the entire HStack as content!
It is better think where you want acutely apply this modification!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, can i still do this even though im using a custom modifier? And i dont want the button to have different modifiers, i want it to have no modifiers at all @swiftPunk